# What's up with all these non-objective questions being upvoted?

Tags: discussion

[Overview book about economic theories](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/526/overview-book-about-economic-theories)

[Are there any non-paywalled reputable economics journals?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/502/are-there-any-non-paywalled-reputable-economics-journals)

[What are some good graduate-level econometrics books for someone with a strong mathematics background?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/495/what-are-some-good-graduate-level-econometrics-books-for-someone-with-a-strong-m)

These kinds of questions are quickly closed on other SE sites, for not being objective.

Comment: Please highlight how these are non-objective. Perhaps you mean "Questions that lead to answers that are objective". We had a post here earlier on meta where we decided to accept recommendations.

Comment: See http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/169/consensus-on-list-questions

Answer (score 7):

All these are "reference-request" type of questions, which can almost never be "objectively" answered. But they are *very* useful because they collect information in one place for interested readers of the post to start digging.
I understand why "opinion-based" Q&A *in general* is not bound to be productive, but such kind of questions (and their answers), are evident exceptions (that at the same time, validate the general rule).
There is also an argument against "list-type" questions, which again I understand its rationale, but which does not hold especially  for sites tangent to scientific research: as I wrote elsewhere "lists weigh their length in gold for the researcher and the graduate student".